# EventHubProducerClient errors when used with lambda

Tags: java, azure, lambda, aws-lambda, azure-eventhub

I have a lambda that takes events from kinesis and writes them to the event hub, In order to achieve this, I'm using EventHubProducerClient. However occasionally I see the following issues,

1.
The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 240000 milliseconds and is closed by container '5da4e040981f4f2ba3467df5b254ee1b_G43'., errorContext[NAMESPACE: namespace, PATH: $cbs, REFERENCE_ID: cbs:sender, LINK_CREDIT: 99]

2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectionId[MF_d6df5a_1641600301779] sessionName[eventHubName] entityPath[eventHubName] linkName[eventHubName] Cannot create send link from a closed session.

Note that I initialize the EventHubProducerClient only once and use the same client for further invocations instead of closing and initializing on every invocation.

I tried looking up and there's little to no information on either of these issues and how to resolve them.

can anyone please help?

Comment: This seems like incorrect behavior to me.  While the link will be force-closed by the service when idle, any attempt to use the producer for an operation should cause an implicit reconnect in the background.   Your code should not have to worry about managing connections explicitly.   I'm going to ask one of the engineers for our Java SDK team to weigh in here.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the code you're using and the version of the client library? When the connection is closed after idling, the client library should recreate it when you go to send a message. Feel free to file issues here as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/